# Running QML/C++ application build with CMake is unable to run from QtCreator or snap package

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am trying to get a QML/C++ application packaged as a snap. I am using CMake as a build system. The application builds fine and I am able to run the executable by double clicking on it. When trying to run it from QtCreator (Ubuntu SDK) I get the following error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The same error is present when trying to run the application from a snap package.

When trying to build and run the application with QtCreator 4.0.2 (manually downloaded and installed) with the same Qt version (5.5.1 that came with Ubuntu 16.04) the application runs without any issues.

[CMakeLists.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17899871/)

[snapcraft.yaml](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17899953/)

All tests were done on Ubuntu 16.04 fully up to date with the ubuntu-sdk ppa added.

UPDATE: Tested on a fresh VM with Ubuntu 16.04 in the hopes that is was just an environment problem and the issue still reproduces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your missing libqt5gui5 from your stage-packages

**UPDATE:**

So to expand my answer a bit more. Here is an simple working example to snap a CMake/Qt/QML application and make it runnable from qtcreator

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

```qml
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import Ubuntu.Components 1.3

Window {
    minimumHeight: units.gu(80)
    minimumWidth: minimumHeight
    MainView {
        applicationName: "simpleapp"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Page {
            title: "Hello world"

            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Quit"
                onClicked: Qt.quit()
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: show()
}
```

```cmake
#CMakeLists.txt
project(simpleapp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Core  REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui   REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Qml   REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE QML_FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.qml")
add_custom_target(qml_files SOURCES ${QML_FILES})

set(CPP_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_FILES} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/qml.qrc)
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Core Gui Qml Quick)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION /bin)
```

```yaml
#snapcraft.yml
name: simpleapp
version: 1.0
summary: Qt Application Example
description: A simple app
confinement: devmode

apps:
  simpleapp:
    command: qt5-launch simpleapp
    plugs:
      - unity7
      - home

parts:
  application:
    plugin: cmake
    source: .
    build-packages:
      - qtbase5-dev
      - qtdeclarative5-dev
    stage-packages:
      - libqt5gui5
      - libgtk2.0-0
      - ubuntu-sdk-libs # probably overkill but fine for this example
    after: [qt5conf] # use the qt5-launch wiki part to setup env
```

To build the snap and run it:

```
$ snapcraft snap
$ sudo snap install simpleapp_1.0_amd64.snap
$ simpleapp
```

And just use the standard run config in qtcreator.

Comment: Thanks but tried both libqt5gui5 and qt5-default. Still the same result sadly.